# Big-O of MySQL Fuzzy Search

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, big-o, fuzzy-search

What is the Big-O of MySQL Fuzzy Search? Does it vary by index type, if so, what performs the best?

e.g. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE field1 LIKE '%ello Wo%';`

I'm unsure of the underlying datatype, what kind of magic it possesses. Something like a trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be nice for search who is fuzzy at the end, e.g. `LIKE 'Hello Wo%'`.

I'm guessing the Big-O is `O(n)` but wish to confirm. There may even be differences between fuzzy searches too, e.g. `%ello Wo%` vs. `Hello W%` vs. `%lo World` vs. `%ell%o%W%or%`

Are there different ways to index that give better performance? If yes, for particular cases, can you please share?

Comment: The full-text search uses [ranking with vector spaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/full-text-search.html). It seems as most fuzzy search algorithms aim for sub-linear (`O(log n)`), and runs in such in practice, however being `O(n)` in theory. See e.g. [this relevant blog post](http://ntz-develop.blogspot.se/2011/03/fuzzy-string-search.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With a leading wildcard**

MySQL will

1. Scan all the rows in the table (not an index).  This is called a "table scan".  (This assuming no other filtering going on.)
2. For each row, scan the column in question for the `LIKE`;
3. Deliver the rows not filtered out.

Most of the time is spent in Step 1, which is O(N) where N is the number of rows.  Much less time is spent in steps 2 and 3.

**Without a leading wildcard**

1. Use an index on that column, *if you have one*, to limit the number of rows to search.  If you have an index on the column and are saying `WHERE col LIKE 'Hello W%'`, it will find all the rows in the index starting with `Hello W`.  They will be consecutive in the index, making this step faster.
2. For each of those, reach into the Data for the row and do whatever else is required.

There are a number of variables (caching, number of rows, randomness of rows, etc) that lead to whether #1 is more or less costly than #2.  But this is likely to be much faster than the leading-wildcard case -- O(n), where `n` is the number of rows starting with 'Hello W'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Rick! Do you know where one could find the official information about the complexity of indexes? Not because I doubt the answer at all, but to learn more and look up different cases.

Comment: @Luc - The "official" documentation for MySQL is online.  The problem is applying it to real life situations.  To that end, I wrote a [_cookbook on how to create an index, given a Select_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).